# Give an example of a subset W that has an injective functional inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V = $[ f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} ]$ be an infinite vector space over field $\mathbb{R}$.

Find a subset $W$ of $V$, such that:

> 1. For arbitrary distinct $f_{1}, f_{2}, ... , f_{n} \in W$, set [$\{f_{1}, f_{2}, ... , f_{n} \}$] is linearly independent.
> 2. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and any $f_{n} \in W = [f_{1}, f_{2}, ... , f_{n}]$,

$$ \exists \text{ a function } H: W \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } H[f_{n}(x)]  = x $$

> 3. For arbitrary $f_{i}, f_{j} \in W$, $$H(f_{i}) = H(f_{j}) \longrightarrow f_{i} = f_{j}$$

In solving this problem, I assumed that condition 2 argues for the existence of an inverse function $f_{i}^{-1}$ for arbitrary $f_{i}$ in $W$.

My approach was to claim:

> 1. Define $W = [f_{i} = e^{ix} \text{ } | \text{ } e^{x}, e^{2x}, e^{3x}, ... , e^{nx}]$
> 2. Define $H(f_{i}) = f_{i}^{1/x} = [e^{ix}]^{1/x} = e^{i}$

My question is:

> 1. Does the above approach, with its definition of $W$ and $H$, satisfy conditions 1, 2, and 3? If not, then are there other possible definitions/examples?
> 2. How would one prove/show the linear independence of set $W = [f_{1}, f_{2}, ... , f_{n}]$?